# How to convert Gregorian date (in seconds) to unix timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, gregorian-calendar

I have a webservice returning timestamps in Gregorian seconds.

How do I convert Gregorian date (in seconds) to unix timestamp in PHP?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

subtract unix epoch(62167219200) from the Gregorian seconds returned by the web service. see [here](http://www.trapexit.org/Converting_DMYHMS_to_Seconds)